# UISegmentedControl Not Honoring NSConstraint for Width

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uisegmentedcontrol, nslayoutconstraint

I have setup a screen with multiple `UISegmentedControl`. Using Auto-Layout/NSLayoutConstraints, I have set the first `UISegmentControl` to have width of "0.9 the width of the superview".

I then set the 2nd and 3rd `UISegmentedControl` to have width equal to the 1st `UISegmentedControl`.

In the end, I am getting `UISegmentedControls` that are not the same width. Depending on the number of segments, the `UISegmentedControl` might have a white space on the right end. With the white space, the entire area is equal to the desired with width - but if I set the background to be transparent, the `UISegmentedControl` is not wide enough, because the segments are not being drawn wide enough.

I have circled the white gap in the attached image.
[image: space on right end of 2nd UISegmentedControl]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you've run into a bug with UISegmentedControl. I found that it is possible to reproduce this even without NSLayoutConstraints, although much less likely!

In your case, your proportional constraint of 0.9 would result in a fractional width on several devices. It appears that the auto-calculated width of the segments does not like this, which is why the gap appears.

I set up a similar view, with three segment controls set to 0.9 of the super view's width.

[image: Three UISegmentControls, with gap showing on right edge]

Now you can see they have the same frames (the white background), but the middle control doesn't fit the whole width.

I was able to correct the problem by overriding viewDidLayoutSubviews in my viewController and adjusting the frame of my segmentedControl if the width is fractional.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]) {
            CGRect frame = subview.frame;
            CGFloat frameWidth = CGRectGetWidth(frame);
            CGFloat roundedWidth = roundf(frameWidth);
            if (frameWidth != roundedWidth) {
                frame.size.width = roundedWidth;
                subview.frame = frame;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces this result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @savvyx4 , but when I use your `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, the values of `frameWidth` and `roundedWidth` are always coming in as equal values, so the width of the `UISegmentedControl` is not adjusting. Thoughts?

Comment: It seems that the `frameWidth` value is the width of the segments + the white space. So when I adjust the `UISegmentedControl.frame`, it is not adjusting the lines drawn for each segment.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was happening because the previous app developer had implemented a subclass of `UISegmentControl`, which was effecting the width of each segment.

I made some adjustments to this subclass, and the `UISegmentControl` began sizing correctly, even when using proportional constraints.

I have not been able to reproduce this problem while using the standard `UISegmentControl` class.

Comment: That would explain the size of your gap compared to the one in my screenshots. I did look at my little sample app to try and understand why you were seeing something different, and I did find that the target device was important. Running on an iPhone 5 would produce different results than a 6 or 6 plus because of the different resolutions (with the issue being most noticeable on the 6 plus).

Glad you found the root cause of your issue, and happy I still found something interesting nonetheless!